# Laravel 5.5. InClassLoader.php line 444

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.5  and am trying to make UsersContoller with this command.

```
php artisan make: controller UsersController --resource --model= User.
```

My error says:

> include(C:\xampp\htdocs\My_laravel\vendor\composer....\app\User.php): failed to open stream: No scuh file or directory

Comment: Am actually new to laravel and it whole programming concept

Comment: `--model= User`  is for type-hinting so you must have created this model first

Answer (score 0):

See this video: http://youtu.be/AjQ5e9TOZVk?t=1m45s You can do php artisan list to view all commands, The command for generating REST-ful controllers is controller:make You can view the usage with: php artisan help controller:make

make:command      =>     Create a new command class

make:console      =>     Create a new Artisan command

make:controller   =>   Create a new resource controller class

make:event        =>   Create a new event class

make:middleware    =>  Create a new middleware class

make:migration     =>  Create a new migration file

make:model         =>  Create a new Eloquent model class

make:provider      =>  Create a new service provider class

make:request     =>    Create a new form request class